# c# Naudio MemoryStream Exception was not readable

Tags: c#, naudio

I'm using Naudio. And I'm trying to write `.mp3` stream to `.wav` stream. This is my code:

```
        MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();                
        WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new Mp3FileReader(@"C:\Users\practice\Desktop\ORIG FILE.mp3"));            
        using (WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputStream, waveStream.WaveFormat))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[waveStream.Length];
            waveStream.Position = 0;
            waveStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)waveStream.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Flush();
        }
        using(WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(outputStream))
        {

        }
        waveStream.Close();
        outputStream.Close();
```

I've got an exception in the second using block: `Stream was not readable.` How can I resolve it?

Comment: Two bugs.  A stream takes ownership of another stream you pass to the constructor.  So your *using* statement also disposes the memory stream.  And you have to set the Position back to 0 to rewind it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your using statement completes the disposable gets disposed.

You can either combine

```
        using (MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (WaveStream waveStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new Mp3FileReader(@"D:\recit.mp3")))
        using (WaveFileWriter waveFileWriter = new WaveFileWriter(outputStream, waveStream.WaveFormat))
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[waveStream.Length];
            waveStream.Position = 0;
            waveStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)waveStream.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            waveFileWriter.Flush();

            outputStream.Position = 0;

            using (WaveFileReader reader = new WaveFileReader(outputStream))
            {}
        }
    }
```

or translate it into try-catch-finally where you would dispose the streams manually

Comment: But I have a question: How can I use outputStream before I've written data to it?

Comment: Not sure what your goal is.
Are you attempting to read from the stream after you wrote to it instead of reading from file?

Have edited my answer accordingly.